# Dates from the last month of specific ranges

Tags: date, crystal-reports

How can I extract data from the previous month into three sections? I can use the function `LASTMONTH` but that gives me the whole month.

I need it split into three sections:

```
1st - 10th of last month
11th - 20th of last month
21st to end of last month
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a two step problem:

1. Write a formula which comes up with 3 values based on date
2. Group and Sort your data based on that formula

---

The formula in question will look something like the following:

```
IF {yourDate} in date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1, 1) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1, 10)
THEN "A"
ELSE IF {yourDate} in date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1, 11) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1, 20)
THEN "B"
ELSE IF {yourDate} in date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1, 21) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)-1
THEN "C"
ELSE "D"
```

Where A, B, and C are valid dates and D is all the invalid ones. Substitute as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks.  I have followed this formula, grouped and sorted but in my test I am getting "D" for all.                                                        if {xdailyissues.issue_date} in date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,1) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,10) THEN "A"
ELSE IF {xdailyissues.issue_date} in date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,11) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,20) THEN "B"
ELSE IF {xdailyissues.issue_date} in date (year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,21) to date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)-1 THEN "C"
ELSE "D"

Comment: Ignore above.  I did something wrong. Will confirm when I know if its worked completely.

Comment: This worked. I cannot see where I can mark this post as "Answered"?

Comment: @IJ76 There should be a checkbox to the left, near the up and down arrows. You'll want to change that from gray to green.